# Different data types in form and database and forward and backward conversion

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I thought it'd be easy but, yeah... it wasn't. I already posted a question that went in the same direction, but formulated another question.

## What I want to do

I have the collection **songs**, that has a **time** attribute (the playing-time of the song). This attribute should be **handled different in the form-validation and the backend-validation!**

## ! I'd like to do it with what  autoform (and simple-schema / collection2) offers me. If that's possible...

- in the **form** the time should be entered and validated as a **string** that fits the regex `/^\d{1,2}:?[0-5][0-9]$/` (so either format *"mm:ss"* or *mmss*).
- in the **database** it should be stored as a **Number**

## What I tried to do

### 1. The "formToDoc-way"

This is my javascript

```js
// schema for collection
var schema = {
    time: {
        label: "Time (MM:SS)",
        type: Number // !!!
    },
    // ...
};
SongsSchema = new SimpleSchema(schema);
Songs.attachSchema(SongsSchema);

// schema for form validation
schema.time.type = String // changing from Number to String!
schema.time.regEx = /^\d{1,2}:?[0-5][0-9]$/;
SongsSchemaForm = new SimpleSchema(schema);
```

And this is my template:

```
{{>quickForm
   id="..."
   type="insert"
   collection="Songs"
   schema="SongsSchemaForm"
}}
```

My desired workflow would be:

1. time is validated as a String using the schema
2. time is being converted to seconds (Number)
3. time is validated as a Number in the backend
4. song is stored

And the way back.

I first tried to use the hook `formToDoc` and converted the string into seconds (Number).

#### The Problem:

I found out, that the **form validation** via the given schema (for the form) takes place **AFTER the conversion in** `formToDoc, so it is a Number already and validation as a String fails.
That is why I looked for another hook that fires after the form is validated. That's why I tried...

### 2. The "before.insert-way"

I used the hook `before.insert` and the way to the database worked!

```js
AutoForm.hooks({
    formCreateSong: {
        before: {
            insert: function (doc) {
                // converting the doc.time to Number (seconds)
                // ...
                return doc;
            }
        },

        docToForm: function (doc) {
            // convert the doc.time (Number) back to a string (MM:SS)
            // ...
            return doc;
        }
    }
});
```

#### The Problem:

When I implemented an `update`-form, the `docToForm` was not called so in the update-form was the numerical value (in seconds).

## Questions:

1. How can I do the way back from the database to the form, so the conversion from seconds to a string MM:SS?
2. Is there a better way how to cope with this usecase (different data types in the form-validation and backend-validation)?

I am looking for a "meteor autoform" way of solving this.

Thank you alot for reading and hopefully a good answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the `time` should really be formatted inside the view and not inside the model. So here's the Schema for `time` I'd use:

```
...
function convertTimeToSeconds (timeString) {
  var timeSplit = timeString.split(':')
  return (parseInt(timeSplit[0]) * 60 + parseInt(timeSplit[1]))
}

time: {
  type: Number,
  autoValue: function () {
    if(!/^\d{1,2}:?[0-5][0-9]$/.test(this.value)) return false
    return convertTimeToSeconds(this.value)
  }
}
...
```

This has a small disadvantage of course. You can't use the `quickForm`-helper anymore, but will have to use `autoForm`.

To then display the value I'd simply `find` the `songs` and then write a helper:

```
Template.registerHelper('formateTime', function (seconds) {
  var secondsMod = seconds % 60
  return [(seconds - secondsMod) / 60, secondsMod].join(':')
})
```

In your template:

```
{{ formatTime time }}
```

Comment: hey, thank you for your advice. I am looking for a "autoform"-way of doing all this. For example instead converting it in the autoValue I also could do it in the `formToDoc` function in case I don't use an extra schema for form browser validation and use `{{#autoForm}}...` and `{{>afQuickField type="string"...}}` It hopefully is possible with what the package offers me. So I am also looking for a way, an autoform update form displays a string in the input field ("MM:SS") instead of the seconds stored in the db. Do you know why my "docToForm" is not called? Or where should I put the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is don't validate the string, validate the number that the string is converted into.

With simpleschema, all you do is create a custom validation. That custom validation is going to grab the string, turn it into a number, and then validate that number.

Then, when you pull it from the database, you'll have to take that number & convert it into a string. Now, simpleschema doesn't do this natively, but it's easy enough to do in your form.

Now, if you wanted to get fancy, here's what I'd recommend:

Add new schema fields:

```
SimpleSchema.extendOptions({
  userValue: Match.Optional(Function),
  dbValue: Match.Optional(Function),
});
```

Then, add a function to your `time` field (stored as Date field):

```
    userValue: function () {
      return moment(this.value).format('mm:ss');
    },
    dbValue: function () {
      return timeToNumber(this.value);
    }
```

Then, make a function that converts a timeString to a number (quick and dirty example, you'll have to add error checking):

```
function timeToNumber(str) {
  str.replace(':',''); //remove colon
  var mins = +str.substr(0,2);
  var secs = +str.substr(2,2);
  return mins * 60 + secs; 
}
```

Then, for real-time validation you can use `schema.namedContext().validateOne`. To update the db, just send `timeToNumber(input.value)`.

Comment: that sounds like I have to go pretty far and write my own autoform template with custom validation triggering and so on? I hoped for a version where I don't have to dig so deep... :-) But if you tell me that it's the only way I try it...